# Apple TV and sites like VideoBB/Screen mirroring/Flash?

Tags: jailbreak, appletv

So lately I've been watching online videos on VideoBB and similar sites, and I'm wondering if I can do this on the Apple TV?

Also, is it possible to mirror my screen to the AppleTV and show Safari, so to play the videos right from there? So far I've looked at...

1. AirFlick - No audio
2. AirDisplay - No audio...
3. ClickToPlugin - Does not work on the VideoBB, "killer" doesn't work.

I'm hoping there's another solution for playing these videos on the AppleTV. If I need to, I will choose a different device, but I would rather stick with the AppleTV for the pretty flawless system that comes with it.

Also, and I'm guessing this is a no, does the AppleTV run flash videos? What about a jailbroken one? Would it be possible to go to VideoBB on a jailbroken AppleTV and just watching the videos through the browser (not sure if one if included with Boxee, Plex, or XBMC).

Answer (score 1):

No, a non-jailbroken Apple TV does not display Flash videos.

I've resorted to downloading videos and converting them to MP4 for the ATV.

Comment: What about something like this? http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=118251&highlight=videozer It says it supports VideoBB, or NitoTv http://wiki.awkwardtv.org/wiki/NitoTV?

Comment: You'd have to try it.  I have no idea what VideoBB or NitoTv are.